# Iterating over R.string.name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm studying Java while developing a small Android Appication. I have my `Question` class defined as:

```
public class Question {
    private int questionId;
    private int answer;

    public Question (int questionId, int answer) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    [...]    //getter-setter

}
```

In `res/values/strings.xml` i have:

```
    <string name="Qst1">Question number 1</string>
    <string name="Qst2">Question number 2</string>
    [...]
    <string name="QstN">Question number N</string>
    <bool name="Ans1">true</bool>
    <bool name="Ans2">true</bool>
    [...]
    <bool name="AnsN">false</bool>
```

Then I created a new class:

```
public class QuestionsList extends ArrayList {

    public void autofill(){
      // autofill the list with the questions
    }
}
```

To obtain a a `Question` object, i usually call the constructor as follow:

`question1 = new Question(R.string.Qst1, R.bool.Ans1)`

**I want to define the method  `autofill` in order to fill `QuestionsList` with all the questions defined in the `xml` file.**
How can I implement it?

Comment: Do you only have question strings in your `strings.xml`?

Comment: No, but I think that I can put them separately in another file like ```questions.xml```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [String array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) and iterate over the array instead. 
I think using string array would be a more androidy way of handling yor problem.
Let me know if you were able to solve your problem!